# BIND error - loading configuration: unexpected end of input

Tags: domain-name-system, debian

This is the error I get when executing /etc/init.d/bind9 restart

```
Jun  1 10:43:29 local-dns named[2922]: starting BIND 9.5.1-P1 -u bind
Jun  1 10:43:29 local-dns named[2922]: found 1 CPU, using 1 worker thread
Jun  1 10:43:29 local-dns named[2922]: using up to 4096 sockets
Jun  1 10:43:29 local-dns named[2922]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
Jun  1 10:43:29 local-dns named[2922]: /etc/bind/named.conf.local:13: unexpected end of input
Jun  1 10:43:29 local-dns named[2922]: loading configuration: unexpected end of input
Jun  1 10:43:29 local-dns named[2922]: exiting (due to fatal error)
```

Here is my /etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     ns1.test.com. (
                        2006020201
                        604800
                        86400
                        2419200
                        604800 )

NS      ns1
MX      10 mail
```

No matter what I do I can't seem to get the unexpected end of input error to go away.  I've tried with a single line after the MX record and having the MX be the last line.  I'm not sure why it's giving this error.  Does anyone know what's up?

Comment: +1 to offset the down vote.  Jeff/Joel have made clear that basic questions are welcomed and "RTFM" responses are not desired.

Comment: I recommend reading http://tldp.org/HOWTO/DNS-HOWTO.html or http://www.isc.org/software/bind/documentation/arm95. Or if you're GUI person, use Fedora/RedHat/CentOS and its system-config-bind tool.
@tomjedrz: I don't like RTFMs, too, but I don't see any value in this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

named.conf.local is where you define zones (domains) you are authoritative for.  You are not supposed to put your DNS records here.

Your named.conf.local should look like this.

```
zone "test.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/test.com.dns";
        allow-query {any;};
};
```

All the stuff you currently have there should be in a file named named **/etc/bind/test.com.dns**.

Comment: right on, that was the issue. props.

Answer (score 1):

And if I may add something, please check again documentation for Bind, 'cause following is not a complete entry:

```
NS      ns1
```